Custom sorting in antd table
What antd table API provides is this
       date: {
            title: "Date",
            dataIndex: 'date',
            key: 'date',
            width: 85,
            showSorterTooltip: { target: 'full-header' },
            sortDirections: ['descend'],
            sorter: (a, b) => a.date - b.date,
        },

and what it does is that it sorts data that is already fetched and in the table.
But I need to fetch data from API whenever sorting direction changes, so I need to somehow know whether user has selected the soring column or not. From what I see there is no way to do it with table API.
Any workarounds ?

You can use onChange function to lister for sort, filter, pagination changes. sorter parameter provided by onChange function can be object or an array if multiple sorter is enabled. In object, order can be ascend, descend or undefined.
Inorder to detect which operation (filter, sorter, pagination) was performed, you can use forth parameter extra action key to check either sorting was performed or pagination....
Here's the complete code:
import { Table } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Table
            columns={[
                { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name', sorter: true },
                { title: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age', key: 'age', sorter: { multiple: 1 } },
                { title: 'Address', dataIndex: 'address', key: 'address', sorter: { multiple: 1 } }
            ]}
            dataSource={[
                { key: '1', name: 'Mike', age: 32, address: '10 Downing Street' },
                { key: '2', name: 'John', age: 42, address: '10 Downing Street' },
                { key: '3', name: 'John', age: 42, address: '10 Downing Street' }
            ]}
            onChange={(_pagination, _filters, sorter, extra) => {
                // action can be "paginate" | "sort" | "filter"
                if (extra.action !== 'sort') return;

                // Remember order can be undefined if sorting is removed
                if (Array.isArray(sorter)) {
                    sorter.forEach((sorterItem) => {
                        console.log(sorterItem.columnKey, sorterItem.order);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(sorter.columnKey, sorter.order);
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default App;

